# What is the best approach to implementing a component that responds to events?

Tags: plugin, extensions, custom-component

I am working on a Component that will add a set of administrative functionality, which I am fairly confident in, but part of its behaviour will rely on code being triggered by events, which seems to be very much the role of a Plug-In.

What is the correct way to structure this if I want the whole lot to be easy to install and maintain? Is there a way to implement Plugin-like Observers in my Component or should I be building a separate Component and Plugin and then chaining the installers somehow? In the latter case how should I manage the code that they both share and ensure that if one is installed the other is too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I woudld suggest you could install the Component and the event triggered Plugins together as a Joomla Installation Package to ensure both are available.

https://docs.joomla.org/Package